# I want to classify all result acquisition of paginated list acquisition API in Go language

Tags: api, go

#### Assumptions

I'm having trouble classifying all the results of the paginated list acquisition API in Go language, so please show me an implementation example.
This post is multi post. Other post is in Japanese below.

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/92728
- https://teratail.com/questions/b3mu9w40b2so3l

#### What I want to achieve

When there was a paginated list acquisition method (=ListSomething) with a request/response object like the following,
I want to create a class to get all the results of that.

```golang
// request request object
type request struct {
nextToken *string
pageSize int
}

// response response object
type response struct {
nextToken *string
rows[]interface{}
}

// MAX the maximum value of the paginated list
var MAX = 20

// ListSomething sample method for getting a paginated list
// Output up to 20 number sequences (0~) for the specified pageSize
func ListSomething(request request) response {
var rows[]interface{}
var nextToken *string

offset, _ := strconv.Atoi(*request.nextToken)
limit := offset + request.pageSize
if limit > MAX {
limit = MAX
nextToken = nil
} else {
limitStr := strconv.Itoa(limit)
nextToken = &limitStr
}
for i := offset; i < limit; i++ {
rows = append(rows, i)
}
return response {
rows: rows,
nextToken: nextToken,
}
}
```

#### Problem/Error Message

I have the image below as an image of the class, but I can't think of a good way to abstract methods and request/response objects.

```golang
// Looper paginated list acquisition class
type Looper struct {
     // abstracted methods and request/response objects
}

// New Looper Looper constructor
func NewLooper(/* abstracted method or request/response object */) *Looper{
     return &Looper{
         // abstracted methods and request/response objects
     }
}

// Loop until Loop response.nextToken == nil and return all results
func (l *Looper) Loop() []interface{} {
firstToken := "0"
nextToken := &firstToken
var ans [] interface {}

for {
response := abstracted method (
/* abstracted request */
)
ans = append(ans, response.rows...)
if response.nextToken == nil {
break
}
nextToken = response.nextToken
}
return ans
}
```

ListSomethingA and ListSomethingB like the following methods for partial acquisition are the objects of abstraction. What they have in common is that requestA/requestB have nextToken and pageSize, and responseA/responseB have nextToken and rows member variables.

- ListSomethingA(request requestA) responseA
- ListSomethingB(request requestB) responseB

```golang
fmt.Println(NewLooper(/*ListSomethingA or responseA or requestA*/).Loop())
// output: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
fmt.Println(NewLooper(/*ListSomethingB or responseB or requestB*/).Loop())
// output: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

#### Supplementary information (FW/tool version, etc.)

Go 1.19